# why is this linked-list add method working?

Tags: javascript, variables, linked-list

I have created this method to add a number into a linked list, but I dont really understand why it is working.

If you take a look at the code bellow you will notice I created a variable named "current", which is set with the content of this.head, till then everything works perfectly but I dont understand why this.head is updating with the value of the current variable if I havent tell Javascript to do so.

this is my code, Ill really apreciate the help you guys can give me

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value, next_node = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next_node = next_node;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  // setup head and tail
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  
  add(number) {
    let node = new Node(number)
    if(this.head === null){
      this.head = node;
    } else {
     let current = this.head;
     while(current.next_node !== null){
       current = current.next_node   
     }
      current.next_node = node;
      console.log(this.head)
    }
    this.length++
  }
  
  get(index) {
  }
}

const ll = new LinkedList();
ll.add(2)
ll.add(3)
ll.add(5)
```

Comment: According to your code, your `LinkedList`'s `this.head` is **always the first `node`** that you added. You only update `this.head` when `this.head === null`.

Comment: Thaks for your answer, but if you console.log(this.head) at the end of the method you will notice it is taking the value of the variable "current".

Comment: No, it isn't. If you look at the last `console.log`, it says `value: 2` at the top, and the nested nodes are linked to the first one, hence, their values are also printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to visiualise the process:

Once you have created the list with `const ll = new LinkedList()`, we can represent the situation as:

```
 ll
  ↓
┌────────────┐  
│ head: null │
│ length: 0  │
└────────────┘
```

Now we execute `ll.add(2)`, which equates `this` with `ll` and we perform `let node = new Node(number)`. That can be depicted as:

```
 ll/this           node
  ↓                 ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐
│ head: null │    │ value: 2        │
│ length: 0  │    │ next_node: null │
└────────────┘    └─────────────────┘
```

The `if` condition is true, so `this.head = node` is executed, and finally `this.length++`. The call to `add` ends, and so the `node` variable is out of scope:

```
 ll/this
  ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐
│ head: ──────── │ value: 2        │
│ length: 1  │    │ next_node: null │
└────────────┘    └─────────────────┘
```

When `ll.add(3)` is executed, we get to the core of your question. Again `let node = new Node(number)` is executed:

```
 ll/this                                  node
  ↓                                        ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐
│ head: ──────── │ value: 2        │    │ value: 3        │
│ length: 1  │    │ next_node: null │    │ next_node: null │
└────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘
```

This time the `if` condition is false, and we execute `let current = this.head`:

```
 ll/this                                  node
  ↓                                        ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐
│ head: ──────── │ value: 2        │    │ value: 3        │
│ length: 1  │    │ next_node: null │    │ next_node: null │
└────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘
                    ↑
                   current
```

As the `while` condition is false, the loop does not iterate, and we execute `current.next_node = node` and `this.length++`:

```
 ll/this                                  node
  ↓                                        ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐
│ head: ──────── │ value: 2        │    │ value: 3        │
│ length: 2  │    │ next_node: ──────── │ next_node: null │
└────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘
                    ↑
                   current
```

This is crucial: as `current` references the same node as `this.head`, the mutation of the node is visible whether you look at it via `this.head` or via `current`: it is the same node.

This should make it clear. Just to complete the example script, let's also execute `ll.add(5)`. At the start of the `while` loop in the `else` block we have this:

```
 ll/this                                                         node
  ↓                                                               ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐
│ head: ──────── │ value: 2        │    │ value: 3        │    │ value: 5        │
│ length: 2  │    │ next_node: ──────── │ next_node: null │    │ next_node: null │
└────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘
                    ↑
                   current
```

Now the loop makes one iteration, making `current` point to the second node instance:

```
 ll/this                                                         node
  ↓                                                               ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐
│ head: ──────── │ value: 2        │    │ value: 3        │    │ value: 5        │
│ length: 2  │    │ next_node: ──────── │ next_node: null │    │ next_node: null │
└────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘
                                           ↑
                                          current
```

And finally, `current.next_node = node` and `this.length++` are executed, after which the variables `node` and `current` end their lives:

```
 ll
  ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐    ┌─────────────────┐
│ head: ──────── │ value: 2        │    │ value: 3        │    │ value: 5        │
│ length: 3  │    │ next_node: ──────── │ next_node: ──────── │ next_node: null │
└────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘    └─────────────────┘
```

This completes the list and indirectly mutates what `ll.head` is referencing.